# iOS - from code to storyBoard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

can i generate automatically storyBoard from existing code?

If not, does someone know a good way to make the connection between the current code and new storyBoard?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what do mean by "make the connection between the current code and new storyBoard"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
can i generate automatically storyBoard from existing code?
```

No, you can't.

You will have to analyze what the code does, and translate it into the new storyboard. Or you can simply use XIB files, this way different persons can tackle different parts of the application, without risking too many conflicts when committing the code.

Comment: You do that when you are connecting `IBOutlets` and `IBActions` between code and XIB/Storyboard. You will need to do it, by hand...

Answer (score -1):

Add a new Storyboard to you project like the pic below :

[image]

and then set its target from Summary -> iPhone/iPodDeployment Info :

[image]

However this is just to make a new MainStoryBoard for your app.

Comment: check out my edit. But the question is what do you mean by make the connection between them ?!

Comment: Thanks, but my question wasn't "wiki - how to create new storyBoard".

Comment: I have code (already have an application running correctly) and i want to add to it a storyBoard.

Comment: ok sorry my misunderstanding. You can ctrl and drag just when you have IBAction or IBOutlet in your code.